# Win7: Taskbar programs look like they're being hovered over when they're not

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Windows 7 Ultimate x64 keeps thinking I'm still hovering over a taskbar program even though I'm no longer hovering over it, resulting in the hover colour and tooltip being displayed when it shouldn't.

In this screenshot, Chrome is my active window, yet iTunes remains lit up because I just hovered over it for a second, even though I've since moved the cursor and clicked on my Chrome window. This is unhelpful and distracting.

[image: Chrome is the active window, yet iTunes retains its hover colour]

This bug is temporarily resolved by logging out, but it comes back after a while, not sure what causes it. This has happened to me on and off over several months. Few days ago I did a format and clean install, ran Windows Update completely, yet this is happening again.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suffer the same issue.  Do you have any non-standard mouse drivers installed, like Logitech SetPoint?

Comment: Nah, I use a Microsoft mouse. Think it happens with and without IntelliPoint, but I'll try installing and uninstalling it to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I just installed 7 Taskbar Tweaker http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker (via http://superuser.com/questions/244781/windows-7-close-on-middle-click-of-taskbar-icon ) and this issue has gone away. Not sure if it will come back or not, but I'm impressed so far.

Comment: related: [How do I keep Windows 7's taskbar icon highlighting from getting stuck?](http://superuser.com/q/292314/57579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about an official cause or fix, but the act of simply installing [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and right click on a taskbar icon, then close the opened menu.

Answer was taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/292314/how-do-i-keep-windows-7s-taskbar-icon-highlighting-from-getting-stuck).