# Tile icons missing from start page in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1703

This started happening recently, the tiles in my start menu are missing icons, but show the correct alt-text and link to the correct programs.

[image: Screenshot of my start page]

My Windows version/build is: `Version 10.0.15063 Build 15063`

I've tried to fix this using [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/app-tiles-disappeared-from-windows-10-start-menu/5d8abf5b-f73b-45f1-9d80-b988cd6da49a), restarting the `Windows Explorer` process, and deleting `iconCache.db`. But these only last so long before the issue crops up again.

This only happens for the 'Pinned Tiles' page. The 'All apps' page displays all the tiles and their respective icons correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen only for Metro apps?

Comment: @Biswa This is a non-touchscreen laptop. They're all installed programs that I've pinned to the start page. Screenshot of start page with temp fix (restarted explorer.exe): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu0dy.jpg

Comment: Your screenshot looks normal.  You also didn’t answer the question

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, sorry about that. I thought metro apps meant touchscreen apps. Is there an alternate definition that I should go with? Edit: I read some links, I don't think these are metro apps, open to be disagreed with

The screenshot intends to show the "correct state" of the start menu. The   screenshot in the original post is for bugged state

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a little digging and experimentation from various sources, I found that saving this as a `.bat` file and running it works (found on a Microsoft answers page)

```bat
@echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
taskkill /f /im shellexperiencehost.exe
timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK > nul
del %localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\* /q
timeout /t 2 /NOBREAK > nul
start explorer
@echo on
```

One day into fix now, issue has not resurfaced so far.

Edit: As of 05-Oct-2017, the issue has not resurfaced. Hope this helps someone in a similar boat

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I'll use this as my main Explorer-fixup script also used for this annoying bug: https://superuser.com/q/61833/37578

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (start-menu tiles in Windows 10 showed no icons); this was only for some of the tiles (most from MS Office apps). the tiles showed only the colour of the app, but no icon. I have small size tiles. When I resized them to large the icons reappeared, and when resizing them to small the icons remained. A bit cumbersome, but it solved the issue for me. I have to check if it will stick.