# Tiles in start menu intermittently become blank

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, modern-ui

Randomly, some of the app tiles in the start menu become blank. It's the same set of tiles for the most part. Every once and awhile, it decides to change to a different set. This is a new computer. I'm using the start menu full screen. Build 15063. The issue is not isolated to Windows 10 applications.

The following *temporarily* resolve the issue:

- Restarting the explorer.exe process
- Rebooting the computer
- Deleting the file at C:\Users[usrname]\AppData\Local\IconCache.db
- Unpinning and repinning to start fixes *that specific* application tile.
- Resizing fixes *that specific* app tile

The problem reappears seemingly at random after an aggravatingly short period of time (1-10 mins).

I wonder if it's related to this: There's a random Windows "dong" sound whenever I resume from sleep or boot up.

[image]

Comment: oddly, it hasn't happened in the last several hours

Comment: and then it's back after waking from sleep

Comment: for me it was related with sleeping too

Comment: I don't know (yet) if it is intermittent for me, but rebooting the computer  (as mentioned in the question) brought back the icon I was missing (Firefox). This problem did in fact happen after using sleep. I am at version 10.0.16299 Build 16299 (that's [1709, Redstone 3, Fall Creators Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1709_(Fall_Creators_Update))).

Comment: See also: [Tile icons missing from start page in Windows 10
](https://superuser.com/q/1255080/115481) and [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1255512/115481)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows update seems to have resolved this issue.

Comment: I still frequently experience this problem, with all available updates installed.