# some start menu icons on Windows 10 are sometimes Blank

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu

i am using windows 10 version 1803 and some of my start menu icons are sometimes blank. Not my Windows icons but some icons from installed program.

Comment: See also: [Tile icons missing from start page in Windows 10
](https://superuser.com/q/1255080/115481) with similar [solution below](https://superuser.com/a/1474582/115481)

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it.

1. Right click on the taskbar.
2. Click on *Taskbar Settings*.
3. Go to the Start Menu settings (on the left-hand side)
4. Turn on *Use Start full screen*.
5. Lave the settings and display your start menu as full screen.
6. Go back to the settings and turn *Use Start full screen* back off.

Comment: Worked for me; you should mark as the accepted answer lol

Comment: This works but it only temporarily, after a while the icons are gone again.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't help me. My icons are good in start menu, but wrong when searching.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't figure out how to do it permanently, but this seems to work for me. I created a file in notepad and saved it as "restart_explorer.bat" and then pasted these 2 lines in there.

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe 
start explorer.exe
```

If it's not restarting your explorer, then you can add a 3rd line with the word pause to see what errors you're getting.

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe 
start explorer.exe
pause
```

This seems to reset my icons, for now. I leave it on my desktop and run it whenever they go blank.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by unpinning the affected Apps and then pinning them back but not from the start menu itself.
I opened the start menu folder:

- user

  `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- common

  `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

And pinned back the Apps.