# All windows icons are missing, for all users

Tags: start-menu, windows-server-2019

We are using Windows server 2019 for remote desktop server, and suddenly all icons goes like this.

[image: sers]

and this happens to every users. Is there any way to fix this? There is no iconcache.db, and a restart didn't build the iconcache.db. Windows Update to the latest one also didn't fix it.

I have also tried to make a new user, and login but it still look the same.

Comment: Similar issue....https://superuser.com/questions/1255080/tile-icons-missing-from-start-page-in-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: @Moab No it is not. The one that you linked HAS iconcache.db, and had to delete it. Mine doesn't even have iconcache.db on every single profile, and thus the solution won't have any effect on me except an error notification that the file I was about to delete is not exists