# Microsoft Windows taskbar bug

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, windows-8.1, taskbar

There has been very strange bug in every version on of Windows from 7 to 10 (Windows 7/8/8.1/10). I have been trying to google it for seven years without success because I don't know how to explain it shortly. So now I will try my best to explain it. The problem is about taskbar icons (from this point I will call this bug "the problem"). It happens once or twice a month and it is resolved after restarting Windows but it is still very annoying. Normally taskbar icons are highlighted when you hover mouse pointer above them. But when this problem happens the last icon you hover stays highlighted until you hover mouse above another icon. There is also another problem. Normally when you hover mouse above the taskbar icon which belongs to currently opened application, after some time application window preview shows up and disappears shortly after you move away mouse from it. But when the problem happens the preview appears instantly and stays even after you move away pointer from application taskbar icon. The preview stays until you move mouse above another icon and the problem continues till restarting Windows. So that's it. I'm not very good at explaining things so that's was the best I could do. Feel free to ask anything in comments to clarify things. To be clear I have never used any third party theme app or anything like it. Because this bug was in all versions of Windows I have used and also I have never seen it on other computera or even heard of it, one might think that problem is with my hardware, so here are some of my laptops specs:

Current Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

CPU: AMD E-450, Zacate 40nm Technology

RAM: 4.00GB DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)

Motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. K53BR (CPU 1)

Graphics:

```
Generic PnP Monitor (1366x768@60Hz)

384MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics (ASUStek Computer Inc)

1024MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series (ASUStek Computer Inc)

CrossFire Disabled
```

Storage: 298GB Western Digital WDC WD3200BPVT-80JJ5T0 (SATA)

Optical Drives: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GT51N

So my questions are:

1) Is anybody there who has the same problem or has even heard of it?

2) Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: So, what is your problem? Is something actually broken or non-functional? You've described an odd little anomaly, but it doesn't sound as though anything is actually broken or not working.

Comment: Also, Microsoft has a very handy Feedback app right in Windows 10 you can use to send Feedback like this to them with.

Comment: Yes, it is functional but it is behaving very strangely. This is my problem. Anyway it's still a bug so I asked (edited) if it is possible to fix it. And thank you for your suggestion, I will definitely send feedback to Microsoft.

Comment: How about a screenshot?  Your written description isn’t very helpful

Comment: I can't screenshot it because it is working normally right now. It only happens sometimes. What is it exactly that you don't understand? Shortly the problem is this: taskbar icons stay highlighted when I move mouse pointer away from them. If you still don't understand there is no way I could explain it any clearer.

Comment: I found another question about it https://superuser.com/questions/61833/windows-7-taskbar-icon-highlight-sticks

Comment: It seems that it's a bug which is still not fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: After all these years I found so much people with the same problem. Can anybody mark this question as duplicate? Or I will delete it  if it isn't well-defined.